# Which control(s) using for a Date Input and a Time input in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

In my WPF application, i would like that my user could input a date, and , **optionnaly** a time.

```
12/03/2013       11:20
```

I can use a DatePicker in WPF for the date, ok, but what for the time ? A simple TextBox ?

What are your advices please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the library WPF Toolkit extended at this address:

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

You have a TimePicker / DateTimePicker, etc all what you want